# Potential Difference and Electric field due to changing magnetic fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image: Induction]

Suppose above Frame is kept in time dependent magnetic field $B=\frac{B_0t}{T}$ where $T,B_0$ are constant , then What will be potential difference between Point $O , A$ and $A , B$ .

I know that potential difference is given by $-\int \vec{E}.\vec{d}s$ and since circular electric field will be generated therefore value of $$V_{OA}=-\int_O^A \vec{E}.\vec{ds}=0$$

but I don't know how to calculate $V_{AB}$ . My instructor just wrote flux $$\phi=\frac{B_0t}{T}\times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}R^2 $$ and then calculated EMF by flux rule as $$-\frac{d\phi}{dt}=-\frac{B_0}{T}\times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}R^2 $$ but I don't understand how he used this method to calculate potential difference.  I know what "flux rule" is but why triangle was taken for calculation of flux? why not some other surface/path? What other method can be used for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I don't understand how he used this method to calculate potential
>   difference.

To be sure, this isn't a calculation of potential difference (since the value is path dependent) but is instead the work associated with moving a unit test charge along the path.

The flux rule is simply that the line integral of the electric field along a *closed* path equals the negative time rate of change of magnetic flux through the surface bounded by the path.

$$\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell} = - \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\Sigma} \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{A}$$

(We assume the path is not changing with time).  The area of the triangle is

$$A = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}R^2$$

and, I assume, $\vec B$ is out of the page thus

$$\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell} = -\frac{B_0}{T}\,A = -\frac{B_0}{T}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}R^2$$

Now, remember that this is over the triangular *closed* path.  However, you've already determined that the line integral along the segments $OA$ and $BO$ give zero so the result is due only to the line segment $AB$.

Note that if you had taken the integral along the circular arc from $A$ to $B$ instead of the line segment, the result would be larger and equal to

$$\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell} = - \frac{B_0}{T}\frac{\pi R^2}{6}$$

Comment: so potential difference is depended ? If two people arrive at two different result as yours are they both correct?

Comment: @Sigma, as I wrote in my first sentence, the result is **not** a potential difference;  PD is path independent.  In this case, the result is path *dependent* so it's not a PD.